# Allow to enable or disable default application in developer portal?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have found this link ! It say ok! [Allow to enable or disable default application in developer portal](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/7333)

But i dont't found tenant-conf.json!

In this link ,[Customize per tenant](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/api-security/api-authentication/secure-apis-using-oauth2-tokens/)it say this file is located in / _system/config/apimgt/applicationdata/tenant-conf.json

But in my carbon,i dont't found this file!
[image: not found apimgt]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From API Manager 4.2.0 onwards the tenant-conf.json configurations were moved to the Admin portal. Please find the details [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/get-started/about-this-release/#api-manager-420) and [here](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/product-apis/advanced-configurations/).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using APIM 4.2.0 or 4.1.0, you can find the tenant-conf in the Admin portal under Advanced Settings. In older versions this is available in the Carbon portal in `/_system/config/apimgt/applicationdata/tenant-conf.json` location.